# Do I have to keep all my UI elements within the safe area defined by the iPhone X?

Tags: iphone, ui-design, user-experience

Suppose this is my game's screen for the iPhone 8:

[image]

I have 7 blue buttons, and one blue bar at the bottom which is used to display commentary text.

I understand that the iPhone X has a safe area. In this case, there would be a bottom inset because of the home indicator and the swiping gestures.

The swiping and the home indicator pose no issue to my players. The game does not use any sort of gestures, and the center button is large enough that the home indicator doesn't really affect its aesthetics.

Given that, **do I still have to avoid the bottom inset?** Am I supposed to keep all my buttons within the safe area defined by the iPhone X even when it doesn't affect my user experience?

If I were to stay within the safe area, then I would have to push the bar and the buttons upwards by several pixels, then the leftmost buttons have to be pushed to the right, and the rightmost buttons to the left. That wouldn't look really great with my game art.

Would my game be rejected if I don't keep my elements inside the safe area?

It ***seems*** like I must indeed keep all my UI elements within that area, based on this image from the keynote:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems caused by placing UI elements outside the safe area. Note that many of these are not unique to iPhone X, and would also apply to CRTs, projectors, or smart watch screens for which a safe area is defined.

Touch handling (input) problems:

- The user may initiate a swipe gesture accidentally while intending to tap your button.
- Inversely, the user may initiate a tap gesture accidentally while intending to swipe the home indicator.
- The user's ability to reach buttons or other controls comfortably, without having to readjust their grip, is hindered.

Design and layout (output) problems:

- As you point out, your buttons would be partially occluded by the home indicator. If you had them at the top (in portrait orientation) or sides (in landscape orientation), they could become occluded by the sensor housing.
- Inversely, the home indicator would be obscured by your button. Looking at the example screenshot from the keynote, you can probably picture how a confused user might not see how to leave the app.
- Being close to the physical edge of the device can hinder the readability of your UI (much like when text is laid out with insufficient margins).
- It will look inconsistent with most other apps, and may give the impression that you didn't take the user's device into consideration when you designed the UI.

Having said that, if your buttons have (for instance) text or icons within the safe area, and the circles are effectively just part of the background (with low contrast against the rest of the background, such as your game scene), that would probably be OK. You'd still have to be careful not to obscure the home indicator, though.